# youtube autoplay - is it possible to skip the loader

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I wanted to use a youtube video as a background for my website (mostly because of their bandwidth check and setting the video quality). When I try to autoplay and loop it though (via setting loop and autoplay parameters), I still have the circular loader there. Is there any chance to automatically start the video with no delays (even if it's going to be a bit laggy on the first load) and then just progress with the download, or should I just give up on it?

Thanks,
E.

E: iframe code here:

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/VID_ID?autoplay=1&loop=1&rel=0&playlist=VID_ID " frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: did you found any solution?

Comment: @ImranBughio Nope, sorry

Comment: @Entalpia I ended up manually playing video first 1st frame after a set timeout equal to video length. Which is kind of a manual solution.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it's possible to immediately start loading your video from YouTube. How about downloading it (I like to use http://www.convertfiles.com) and then using that? It'll probably be easier to customize your video options when you have it downloaded on your website.

Comment: Frankly, I wanted to embed it as a HTML5 video, just with youtube it was much easier to control the video quality (it sets the quality proper for internet connection speed - guess it might be causing the delay, cause I was trying to insert the proper quality by myself checking the bandwidth first with Javascript, but it was taking around 7-8 seconds).